# How to increase timeout of Azure App Service for my ASP.NET Core 2.0 API

Tags: azure, iis-8, web.config-transform, kudu, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 API I am deploying to an Azure App Service. This has been working fine until recently when I had to process a request that took longer than 2 minutes to complete and I got a 502 Bad Gateway stating

```
"The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process".
```

This consistently happens when I hit the 2 minute mark on this process.

My diagnostic logfile says

```
018-05-25 02:07:01.462 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

I am working on the assumption that this is a timeout issue because it is always at the 2 minute mark and I know the request takes more than 2 minutes to complete. So I was looking into how to increase the timeout and found some posts on SO that talked about using an applicationHost.xdt file, placing it in the root of the Site folder for the site. I am using this XML;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.applicationHost>
    <webLimits xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(connectionTimeout)" connectionTimeout="00:05:00" />
  </system.applicationHost>
</configuration>
```

When I upload it, using Kudu debug console, to the root of the Site folder for my deployment slot I am using to test my API and then look at the transform file, I see the following;

```
2018-05-24T19:34:19 Start 'site' site extension transform
2018-05-24T19:34:19 StartSection Executing SetAttributes (transform line 4, 16)
2018-05-24T19:34:19 on /configuration/system.applicationHost/webLimits
2018-05-24T19:34:19 Applying to 'webLimits' element (no source line info)
2018-05-24T19:34:19 Set 'connectionTimeout' attribute
2018-05-24T19:34:19 Set 1 attributes
2018-05-24T19:34:19 EndSection Done executing SetAttributes
2018-05-24T19:34:19 Successful 'D:\home\site\applicationHost.xdt' site extension transform
```

which to me looks like it successfully applied the XDT transform.

However even after restarting the base App Service and the related deployment slot. I am still getting the error.

So, am I using the wrong timeout setting?

When I look at the web.config file in my slots sites/wwwroot folder, it contains only this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Mypp.dll" 
stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
```

I expected to see the information about the connectiontimeout that was in the XDT file I applied. So, perhaps this is not the right web.config file?

I am not an Azure expert and at this point, I feel like I am wasting time so I wanted to check an see if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**requestTimeout**:

> Specifies the duration for which the ASP.NET Core Module waits for a response from the process listening on %ASPNETCORE_PORT%.
>
> In versions of the ASP.NET Core Module that shipped with the release of ASP.NET Core 2.0 or earlier, the requestTimeout must be specified in whole minutes only, otherwise it defaults to 2 minutes.

You could try to add the `requestTimeout="00:20:00` in web.config in your slots sites/wwwroot folder.

```
<aspNetCore
  requestTimeout="00:20:00"
  processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%"
  arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"
  stdoutLogEnabled="false"
  stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
  <environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="staging" /> <!-- value could be "development", "staging" or "production"-->
  </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

For more details, you could refer to this article to learn about [ASP.NET Core Module configuration reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.0#attributes-of-the-aspnetcore-element)

Comment: @Joey_Cai, This got me past the 502 error so I am going to mark it as the answer. I now have an issue with the Azure 230 second request timeout limit. My process is taking 3 minutes and 52 seconds :/. I have found that if I scale up my App Service from  S1 to P1V2, it seems to get past the 230 second limit.

Comment: You should look at decoupling those long running requests with a `202 Accepted` and a queue-triggered WebJob. Your current approach is flawed, a request that takes 3 minutes to process is not an interactive request by any standard and you're only delaying the inevitable (fixing the root cause).

Comment: @evilSnobu This API endpoint is called by a service and not an interactive browser session. The service can't move on in its process until it receives the response from my API. Are you recommending that I use a callback anyway and make the service loop until it gets my response or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: If it's service to service you should use a work-queue and a result-queue. Storage Queues or Service Bus Queues if you need guaranteed FIFO ordering. Either place the messages directly in the queue or have your API endpoint `201 Accepted` back to caller and have that place the message in the work-queue. I'd go for the first option, no need to involve HTTP in this.