# ASP.NET Core 2.0 how to increase IIS Express request timeout in launchSettings.json

Tags: visual-studio-2017, web-config, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-express, web-config-transform

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 API that I am trying to debug using VS2017 / IIS Express on my local Win10 dev computer and I am running into an issue with IIS Express in that it is hitting the response timeout default of 2 minutes before my process can complete in my API, thus returning a 502.3 - Bad Gateway message.

I process continues to run in my API and completes after 3 minutes and 50 seconds. So, I need to increase the request timeout for IIS Express.

Most of the examples I have found on the web talk about using the web.config, for example;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00" processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyAPI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

... but from what I understand, An ASP.NET Core 2.0 API running on the local IIS Express doesn't uses a web.config from my project bt rather, it relies on launchSettings.json in the project. However, I have not been able to find anything on the web that talks about launchSettings having any settings values for increasing default timeouts.

Just to confirm, I tried putting a web.config file, like what I listed above, in my project's wwwroot folder, but it made no difference. This worked on my deployed solution in Azure ([see related Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50520779/how-to-increase-timeout-of-azure-app-service-for-my-asp-net-core-2-0-api/50520957#50520957)) but doesn't in IIS Express on my local dev.

This seems like it should be a simple task but so far I have not had any luck finding a solution.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 5/27/18 - SOLUTION**

IIS Express with ASP.NET Core 2.0 uses a file similar to a web.config called applicationhost.config, which is located in the project root/.vs/config folder. This file has a

```
<configuration><Location> ... <location</configuration>
```

section similar to what I have listed below. This section has the

```
<aspNetCore ... />
```

node where I was able to apply the requestTimeout value. By setting that, my dev system was able to get past the default 2 minute timeout.

```
<location path="MyAPI">
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicCompression>
        <add mimeType="text/event-stream" enabled="false" />
      </dynamicCompression>
    </httpCompression>
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00" processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Did you know you could add the solution as an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood the concepts.

`launchSettings.json` is only used by Visual Studio to determine how to run your web project. (More info in [my blog post](https://blog.lextudio.com/what-should-you-check-when-visual-studio-cannot-debug-asp-net-core-projects-4b5db8c5e129))

IIS Express still relies on `web.config` to read the settings, as that's the only file it understands.

Comment: This answer led me to the solution as described in my OP edit above.